# Directive Causes Input to Lose Focus

Tags: angular

I created this directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'input[numbersOnly]'
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {

  constructor(private ref: ElementRef, private control: NgControl) { }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event']) onInputChange(event: Event) {
    const initalValue = this.ref.nativeElement.value;
    this.ref.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, '');
    this.control.control.patchValue(this.ref.nativeElement.value);
    if (initalValue !== this.ref.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

and am using it here:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="quantity">
  <th
    class="header-title-2"
    mat-header-cell
    *matHeaderCellDef
    mat-sort-header="quantity"
  >
    Quantity
    <div class="sort-indicator" [ngClass]="{ desc: sortDirection }">
      {{ sortIndicator('quantity') }}
    </div>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
    <input
      [ngClass]="{ 'input-error': item.quantity > 99 }"
      matInput
      numbersOnly
      class="input-background"
      [(ngModel)]="item.quantity"
      (ngModelChange)="updateQuantity(item)"
      maxlength="99"
    />
    <div class="quantity-error" *ngIf="item.quantity > 99">
      Max quantity is 99
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

However, every time I type a character into the input it loses focus causing the user to have to re-focus it to enter for characters.

I've tried getting a handle on the nativeElement's input and call the focus method but that doesn't seem to do anything even when using a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

It was in fact the ngModelChange that was causing the issue. I changed that to use the blur method and that fixed the problem.

To add more I'm using async pipes to bind the data and I was updating my state model on every key press which I believe this triggered an update which reloaded my data on the page causing the input to lose focus. Basically it was re-rendering pieces of the page that was changed like it's supposed to and that in turn removed the focus.

Hope this helps someone.